Issue with focus when using the viewfinder
I've got a Sony A6500 with a Sigma lens (30mm 1.4 DC-DN).
When I take a picture of a landscape (all green squares appear when focusing) it works nicely. However, if I take the same picture (with again all green squares when focusing) but this time looking through the ViewFinder (rather than looking at the screen) then the output picture isn't sharp anymore. The difference in Lightroom is shocking!
Any idea? (I have the latest firmwares installed)
More details:
-Camera used in Manual Mode
-Autofocus set to AF-S (Single-Shot AF)
-Focus Area: Wide
-Aperture f7.1
-Shutterspeed 1/1600 sec
-ISO 4000
-Focus Length 30mm

Resized photo when using the back display. The enlarged portion shows the sharpness of the image file.

Resized photo when using the EVF. The enlarged portion shows the softness of the image file.

Link to pictures (resized to 60% and RAW converted to jpg):
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fDJL31gtBonSNLVOwkWaJaMV20zfocu2?usp=drive_link


Well, are you using autofocus or manual focus or what? Have you performed a side-by-side comparison of exactly the same scene? Do you notice anything strange about the Exif data recorded alongside each picture?

Is the camera on a tripod when using the monitor screen,  and not when using the viewfinder?

@osullic I have updated the description with more details and side by side picture examples

@StevenKersting I have updated the description with more details and side by side picture examples

I put the images into the posting and edited them so the problem is easily visible

@KaiMattern Thank you very much

The focussing system of the Sony 6500 does not make differences if you use the viewfinder or the back display. However, there is one feature that could be the culprit:
The Eye-Start AF function:
https://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1640/v1/en/contents/TP0001273831.html
This starts the AF the moment you put the camera to the face. I have never used it, but it is worth a try to turn off if enabled. Note, that this is not the Eye AF feature, which focusses on the eyes of a subject in the image. It is just named really badly.
As you are in settings that should produce sharp results, the results are quite puzzling - to the point where it is difficult to figure out what went wrong.
At 1/1600 sec, 30mm and f7.1 the focus needs to be really off to produce this kind of softness. At a subject distance of appr 6m there is quite a big depth of field which should produce a reasonably sharp result.

This basically leaves these things that could have gone wrong:

AF wide is choosing something in the full width of the image. It could be that the focus was really picking something that moved the focus out of the expected range. What is speaking against this, is that there is nothing critically sharp in the image. The twigs in the left area seem to be sharper than the fence. But again, then the focus is so off, that we cannot see what the focus plane was. And unfortunately, Sony does not save the focus distance to EXIF

Depending on the settings, even with the 5-axis stabilizer in the camera, you can still have exposure settings where you create enough camera shake that the image is not sharp. At 1/1600 this should not be the issue.

You could have theoretically have focussed accidentally before you raised the camera fully to the eye. If the finger still rested on the button, then the camera will not refocus due to single AF setting. However, this would be such a quirky edge case. It sounds as if you had your issue multiple times.


But be warned:  I just confirmed with my Sony a7r IV that the green focus squares would not change after keeping the shutter half pressed. This can lead to the illusion that the camera has acquired focus even if the situation has completely changed. You should change the AF-S setting to AF-C and check if the issue is still there.

This leads to the Eye Start AF... I am not sure if that is locking focus at all - but seeing all the clues, please turn off this feature if it is enabled. There might be a bug that it locks a single AF action which then looks like the focus was acquired, when it simply is not. On a second note: Eye Start AF might not even be available with a third party lens.

Last option would be a very quirky defect of the camera or lens. You can never fully rule that one out.



I have updated the description with more details and side by side picture examples. Can you please detail your comment " if we are super exact, there is one feature which does pre-focussing when using the viewfinder"?

Changed the answer to the new information. Hope it helps.


The issue appears in all pictures for which I use the EvF
The Eye Start AF is not available for this lens (I can't change it). I tried with another lens (Sony pancake): Eye Start AF cannot be changed either BUT the images are perfect with the EvF. Very strange!


Did you have a chance to test if the issue persists with AF-C?

It works fine in AF-C, suggesting that the 'bug' is with CDAF. I tried to play with the 'Priority Set in AF-S' and 'Priority Set in AF-C' settings (assuming that it changes from CDAF to PDAF) but no impact to my issue

At that point I would recommend to look for a way to test another copy of the a6500 in a shop or so. Tell them you would like to do a test shot in the show. They also may have another lens to test. Just to find out if it is the lens or the camera. This issue is really odd.

Diopter Adjust not set:
Surrounding the eyepiece of the viewfinder is a circular notched ring. The serrations on this ring improve your grip as you turn this ring for adjustment. Many camera users are near or far sighted and thus see an out-of-focus view when looking through the camera’s viewfinder. To adjust. Take aim on a brick building, allow the camera to automatically focus. Now turn this diopter adjusting wheel to find a position that clears up your view. You are focusing the viewfinder eyepiece, customizing it for your eyes.
Why the industry jargon? Opticians usually express the power of a lens referring to its focal length using millimeters as the unit of measure. Eye doctors prefer to use a different unit called diopter. We can express the power of a lens using any available unit of measure. Example: A 50mm can be expressed as 1/50 X 1000 = 20 written as 20d pronounced 20 diopter.
Reading eyeglasses are rated as to their strength stating their power in diopters. We are talking about the add at the bottom of spectacles. Older folks usually need +2d or +2 ½d add (bifocal) as this will enable them to focus on a book or newspaper about 10 or 12 inches distant.
Your camera features an eyepiece adjustment that provides this add so you can work the viewfinder without your eyeglasses.

Diopter adjustment could be the cause, but if the OP is using autofocus, then it's unlikely to be—because a camera's autofocus is unaffected by the diopter setting, and the OP specifically mentions that focus appears off when the photos are viewed in Lightroom (so we are indeed talking about resultant photos and not just the view when composing). BTW, you suggest using a brick wall for the diopter adjustment—I prefer to use a simple LCD such as the clock on a microwave oven—it's very easy for your camera to focus on, and very easy for the user to then additionally adjust the diopter as needed.

OP states that AF is used and the images look terrible in Lightroom, which indicates that this is not a diopter problem.
